# Assembly loading problems when using Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll in my project

Tags: windows-phone-7, json.net

> Error 2   Could not load the assembly
>   file:///C:\Users\Jitendra\Downloads\Json40r1\Bin\WindowsPhone\Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll.
>   This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly
>   has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a
>   Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent
>   it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by
>   changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more
>   information.

I am getting error like this into the window phone 7 once I added newtonsoft.Json.dll

how I can overcome this problem.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: C:\Users\Jitendra\Downloads\Json40r1\Bin\WindowsPhone

Right click on "Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll"

Select "Properties"

Find and Press "Unlock" (Should be present in the General tab)